# concatenate combobox values in c# from a web service

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

I have no way of modifying the web service and I want to be able to add the 2 columns together with a space in between. While adding this to a combo box. Can someone help? I tried adding "SiteId" + "" + "SiteName". But I am not sure how to call these values while working with a Soap method to add the 2 columns and display in one combo-box.

Any tips or help would be great!

```
         MyServices.OnlineReservationService getSites = new MyServices.OnlineReservationService();
        DataSet dd = new DataSet();
        dd = getSites.GetSites();


        CmbSite.DataSource = dd.Tables[0];
        CmbSite.DisplayMember = "SiteId";
```

Comment: may be you can convert the objects you get from the service to a usable UI side object and then set the combobox

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataSet dd = new DataSet();
        dd = getSites.GetSites();
dd .Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string), "SiteId+ ' ' + SiteName");

dropdownlist1.DataSource = dd.Tables[0];;
CmbSite.DisplayMember= "Display";
CmbSite.Valumember= "SomeValue";
CmbSite.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried adding that and I am getting errors on Columns, dropdownlist1, and databind. Can I do this with a dataset? Do I need to add another system reference?

Comment: Should I be converting this to a datatable, because I can't use the Columns in the dataset

Comment: you can use like this                     dd.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string), "SiteId+ ' ' + SiteName");